# How to post data on JSON web services in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8

I want to post data on JSON web services for login credentials for user.

I use the below code to post data on JSON web service.

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Create a new HttpWebRequest object.
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://test/TestService/Service.svc/json/Login");

        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        //request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0; Touch)";
       // request.CookieContainer = cookie;

        // Set the Method property to 'POST' to post data to the URI.
        request.Method = "POST";

        // start the asynchronous operation
        request.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback), request);

    }
private void GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
    {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;

            // End the operation
            Stream postStream = request.EndGetRequestStream(asynchronousResult);

            //postData value
            string postData = "{'userid': '" + textUserid.Text + "','password':'" + textPassword.Text + "'}";

            // Convert the string into a byte array. 
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

            // Write to the request stream.
            postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, postData.Length);
            postStream.Close();

            // Start the asynchronous operation to get the response
            request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponseCallback), request);

    }
private void GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
    {

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
            // End the operation

            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);

            Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream();

            StreamReader streamRead = new StreamReader(streamResponse);
            string read = streamRead.ReadToEnd();

            //respond from httpRequest
            //TextBox.Text = read;
            MessageBox.Show("Your Response: " + read);
            // Close the stream object
            streamResponse.Close();
            streamRead.Close();
            response.Close();
    }
```

and I import following namespace in my code

```
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using System.Text;
```

I am calling Button_Click_1 method clicking login button from my Windows Phone simulator.

But I am getting this error:

```
Error   1   'System.Net.WebRequest' does not contain a definition for 'GetRequestStream' and no extension method 'GetRequestStream' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Net.WebRequest' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) E:\Users\maan\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\TestWebservice\TestWebservice\MainPage.xaml.cs  99  39  TestWebservice
```

and

```
Error   2   'System.Net.WebRequest' does not contain a definition for 'GetResponse' and no extension method 'GetResponse' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Net.WebRequest' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   E:\Users\maan\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\TestWebservice\TestWebservice\MainPage.xaml.cs  106 39  TestWebservice
```

Please help me I am new to developing Windows mobile application.

Comment: have you enabled "Networking" capability in app manifest file?

Comment: The errors seem to be saying that the app can't find the expected methods. Did you have methods called 'GetRequestStream' or 'GetResponse'? Have you tried renaming 'GetRequestStreamCallback' to 'GetRequestStream' and 'GetResponseCallback' to 'GetResponse'?

Comment: @Ritesh I already added my web service url in web service reference parameter of my app for authentication.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check the below code, i hope it will help you:

```
void sendRequest()
{
   Uri myUri = new Uri(http://www.yourwebsite.com);
   HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(myUri);
   myRequest.Method = AppResources.POST;
   myRequest.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback), myRequest);
}

void GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult callbackResult)
{
    HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)callbackResult.AsyncState;

    // End the stream request operation
    Stream postStream = myRequest.EndGetRequestStream(callbackResult);

    // Create the post data
    string postData = "INSERT HERE THE JASON YOU WANT TO SEND";
    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

    // Add the post data to the web request
    postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    postStream.Close();

    // Start the web request
    myRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponsetStreamCallback), myRequest);
}

 void GetResponsetStreamCallback(IAsyncResult callbackResult)
 {
     lib = new ApiLibrary();

     try
     {
         HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)callbackResult.AsyncState;
         HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(callbackResult);
         string result = "";
         using (StreamReader httpWebStreamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
         {
             result = httpWebStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
         }

            string APIResult = result;

         }
         catch (Exception e)
         {

      }
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but where is ApiLibrary class.

Comment: you dont need the ApiLibrary its just something i created. just delete it

Comment: It gives Exception like UnauthorizedAccessException was unhandled by user code at code line "string postData = "{\"userid\":\"" + textUserid.Text + "\",\"password\":\"" + textPassword.Text + "\"}";"

Comment: put textUserid.Text and textPAssword.text values in state[] then within the postData = {\"userid\":\"" + Session["user"].ToString() + "\",\"password\":\"" + Session["Password"].ToString() + "\"}

Comment: There is an exeption if not set content for request:
myRequest.ContentType = "application/json";